# How to use nsITextInputProcessor in Gecko Fx 60 C#?

Tags: c#, geckofx

I'm using Gecko Fx 60 (C# code) and I want to use nsITextInputProcessor to send key to DOM.

I have a reference on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsITextInputProcessor. But i can't..

Code create an instance :

```
Gecko.nsITextInputProcessor test = Gecko.Xpcom.GetService<Gecko.nsITextInputProcessor>("@mozilla.org/text-input-processor;1");
        test = Gecko.Xpcom.QueryInterface<Gecko.nsITextInputProcessor>(test);
```

Thanks you .

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use different solution without ***nsITextInputProcessor***  try this:

```
public void SendKeys(string message)
{
    foreach (char c in message)
    {
        _browser.Window.WindowUtils.SendNativeKeyEvent(0, 0, 0, c.ToString(), c.ToString());
        Task.Delay(10).Wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[another question about geckofx nsITextInputProcessor use](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0/issues/35/use-nsitextinputprocessor-instead)

The example code from that question:

```
    private void SendKeyEvent(string type, string key, bool alt, bool ctrl, bool shift)
    {
        // Escape for JS.
        key = key.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
        var instance = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsITextInputProcessor>("@mozilla.org/text-input-processor;1");
        using (var context = new AutoJSContext(Window))
        {
            var result = context.EvaluateScript(
                $@"new KeyboardEvent('', {{ key: '{key}', code: '', keyCode: 0, ctrlKey : {(ctrl ? "true" : "false")}, shiftKey : {(shift ? "true" : "false")}, altKey : {(alt ? "true" : "false")} }});");
            instance.BeginInputTransaction((mozIDOMWindow)((GeckoWebBrowser)this).Document.DefaultView.DomWindow, new TextInputProcessorCallback());
            instance.Keydown((nsIDOMEvent)result.ToObject(), 0, 1);
            instance.Keyup((nsIDOMEvent)result.ToObject(), 0, 1);
        }

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance);
    }
```